# NeoVim/Vim showing wrong Python version

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, neovim, pyenv

I used to have Python `3.8-dev` installed via `pyenv` but later I uninstalled this version. Now I only have `3.7.5` installed on my machine. `pyenv versions` results:

[image]

Now I believe the global default is also `3.7.5`. However, when I open a python file using either NeoVim or Vim, from the bottom bar it still shows `Python 3.8.1 64-bit` although I believe I don't have that version on this machine at all. Any idea why this would happen? I believe it's because somehow Vim still thinks I have the `3.8.1` version but don't know how to fix it. Thanks!

[image]

Vim v8.1
NeoVim v0.4.3

Comment: Please [dont post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 6):

You could specify the python version you have on your computer
first, locate your python interpreter with:

`which python`

then you take that output and on top of your .vimrc ( for vim ) or init.vim ( for neovim ) :

```
let g:python3_host_prog = expand('/path/to/your/python')
```

hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this is the `coc.nvim` extension `coc-python`. You need to manually set `:CocCommand python.setInterpreter` to pick the right python version in neovim. Related [issue](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python/issues/55) is here.